# gitignore not works sometimes

Tags: git, ignore

I have simple issue. I want to ignore entire directory. in .gitignore I added `/**/my_folder_with_is_in_root`. I also tried `my_folder_with_is_in_root/` or `/**/my_folder_with_is_in_root/`. but when I changed file content somewhere inside of this folder and git status gives me message that file changed. how ignore folder? sometimes it works for certain folders. cache problem or what? please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found answer `git rm -r --cached my_folder_with_is_in_root/`